# Incorrect header check zlib python

Tags: python, encryption, base64, gzip, zlib

I am extracting data from an API which explains that it is encoded into base64 with gzip. So I wrote this code to try and extract it.

```py
import base64
import zlib

encoded_data = "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"
decoded_data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(encoded_data))

decoded_string = decoded_data.decode("utf-8")

File_object = open(r"test.nbt", "Access_Mode")
File_object.write(decoded_string)
File_object.close()
```

Issue is,

`zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

I have seen online that this could mean that the key is incorrect, but the people online say this is the correct method. If it's not, could you help me decrypt it with the correct method?

Comment: Well, which is it, zlib or gzip? They are different formats and different python packages. Use the gzip package.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed gzip data, so you need to tell `decompress` that. Try `zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(encoded_data), wbits=31)`. Otherwise it is trying to interpret it as a zlib stream, which it isn't.